# Laravel - Nexmo not picking up credentials in .ENV file

Tags: php, laravel, vonage

I recently added laravel/nexmo-notification-channel to my laravel project which also installed Nexmo/nexmo-laravel.

After installing, I published vendor files so that I get **config/nexmo.php** and in there I noted that it looks in the .env file for **NEXMO_KEY** and **NEXMO_SECRET**.

So I went ahead and created these within my .env file

```
NEXMO_KEY=[my_key]
NEXMO_SECRET=[my secret]
NEXMO_SIGNATURE_SECRET=[my signature secret]
```

After this, I added Nexmo to my service providers in app.php:

```
'providers' => [
    ...,
    Nexmo\Laravel\NexmoServiceProvider::class
]
```

and also added the following in **config/services.php**:

```
'nexmo' => [
    'key' => env('NEXMO_KEY', ''),
    'secret' => env('NEXMO_SECRET', ''),
    'sms_from' => '[my number]'
],
```

But I still get the following error when thrying to send an SMS using the **use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\NexmoMessage;** class:

```
"message": "Provide either nexmo.api_secret or nexmo.signature_secret",
```

I can use these same credentials to send an SMS from CLI, so why can't I send it from laravel?

Comment: Maybe the config was cached. You can recache it using `php artisan config:cache`.

Comment: I've tried this a few times, unfortunately that is not the problem =/

Comment: I'm using Laravel 7 and a trial Nexmo account, I'm not sure if either of these could cause some issues?

Comment: Does `env('NEXMO_KEY')` give you any output? If yes, the trail account could be the issue, but I presume some 5-6 messages should be free for a trail one for sandbox testing.

Comment: yes it does give me the right output. What about the Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\NexmoMessage class? Am I using it correctly by setting up Nexmo in this way?

Comment: TBH, I have never used this package personally, so can't guide you much on that.

Answer (score 1):

There have been a couple of workarounds for this that are valid, but at first glance it looks like the Nexmo package does the work to bring in the ENV secrets into Laravel's config. Because of caching problems, you should never call `env()` within Laravel, instead you should be using `config()` - so in this case, `config(nexmo.api_secret)`.

My main point here though is that I can't look into the "correct" solution for you because the package is abandoned. Nexmo is no longer Nexmo, it's Vonage, and Laravel core team have subsequently updated the `notification-channel` package.

For supported use to integrate Vonage services (SMS), please use the following package:

https://github.com/laravel/vonage-notification-channel

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why, but, Vonage/Nexmo doesn't pick details from the `.ENV`.

Instead, use a global constant to fetch the secrets:

Create a `global.php` file in the `config` folder, and add your secrets from the env like this:

```
<?php

return [
  // Other constants values
  'SMS_API_KEY' => env('SMS_API_KEY', ''),
  'SMS_API_SECRET' => env('SMS_API_SECRET', ''),
]

?>
```

Then, you can use the constants in your controller as usual:

```
   'key' => config('global.SMS_API_KEY'),
   'secret' => config('global.SMS_API_SECRET')
```

then: recache, `php artisan config:cache`